# f2py array dependence on an imported parameter

Tags: python, arrays, fortran, f2py

I'm trying to wrap a sizeable Fortran library in Python. I can modify the source code, but obviously want to modify as little as possible. There are a number of fixed-size arrays defined in the code, with lower and/or upper indices specified by parameters from a lower-level module. So it might have statements like

```
use parrrsw, only : j1, j2
integer(kind=4), intent(in), dimension(j1:j2) :: opt_depth
```

In trying to figure out how to adapt to this using f2py, I created the following minimal example to show an error I've been getting. Essentially, it appears that f2py can identify the indices imported from `rrsw`, but somehow fails in using them to assign to the array if they were also used to initialize the array. I think I might be using f2py's `depend` statement wrong, but I haven't yet found an example that would help me fix it.

(Actually, most of the arrays are initially defined as allocatable but later filled in with parameters. That's another issue entirely...but if anyone has a good way to adapt when the code's been written systemically in that way, I'd love to hear it.)

Edit 2016-06-13: I have decided to try using CFFI or ctypes to do my module importing. This question still stands as-is, but it's no longer critical for my work.

Example code:
test_rrsw.f90:

```
module test_rrsw
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: im = selected_int_kind(6)
  integer(kind=im), parameter :: jpb1=16, jpb2=20
  integer(kind=im), parameter :: ng16=6, ng17=12, ng18=8, ng19=8, ng20=10
end module test_rrsw
```

test_minimal.f90:

```
module test_minimal
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: im = selected_int_kind(6)
  integer, parameter :: rb = selected_real_kind(12)
  contains
  subroutine test_pars1(ng)
    use test_rrsw, only : jpb1, jpb2, ng16, ng17, ng18, ng19, ng20
    implicit none
!f2py integer intent(out) :: ng(16:20)
    integer(kind=im), intent(out), dimension(16:20) :: ng
    ng(jpb1:jpb2) = (/ ng16, ng17, ng18, ng19, ng20 /)
  end subroutine test_pars1
  subroutine test_pars2(ng)
    use test_rrsw, only : jpb1, jpb2, ng16, ng17, ng18, ng19, ng20
    implicit none
!f2py integer intent(aux) :: jpb1, jpb2
!f2py depend(jpb1,jpb2) :: ng
!f2py integer intent(out) :: ng(jpb1:jpb2)
    integer(kind=im), intent(out), dimension(jpb1:jpb2) :: ng
    write(*,*) jpb1, jpb2
    ng(jpb1:jpb2) = (/ ng16, ng17, ng18, ng19, ng20 /)
  end subroutine test_pars2
end module test_minimal
```

test.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import test_minimal
res1 = test_minimal.test_minimal.test_pars1()
res2 = test_minimal.test_minimal.test_pars2()
print 'pars1 =', res1, ' pars2 =', res2
```

run_test.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
gfortran -c test_rrsw.f90
gfortran -c test_minimal.f90
f2py -c test_minimal.f90 test_rrsw.o -m test_minimal > log_f2py.txt
python test.py
```

Using `./run_test.sh` produces the output from calling the two different subroutines, `test_pars1` and `test_pars2`, from Python. (Warning: Sometimes I get a segfault when *exiting* Python after running these routines.) If any of these don't work for you, let me know. This is a lot of code, but I wanted to be as explicit about compiling/linking/testing as I could.